# prevent focus on next input while the previous input is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

can anyone tell me how to prevent focus on next input while the previous input that should filled by some code (like an employed code ect) is empty, and it's without auto fill either. and i use codeigniter.

the script should on one file (like footer.php) and used by some page with different object name.

like there is 5 object

1. employed code (can't empty)
2. employed name (can't empty)
3. employed address (it's oke if empty)
4. employed level (can't empty)
5. employed nickname (it's oke if empty)

so i can't click object 3 when object 1 or 2 is empty 
but i can click object 4 if then object 1 and 2 is filled even object 3 is empty.

but the function will used by called employed menu, region menu, ect.

hope it will simple script because i'm new. :)

thanks.

Comment: it's a bad idea to mess with the focus (you can hang your browser trying to force it to some input). You should do your validation on the form submit event.

Comment: it's because some user use mouse often and skip to fill some object. because that the web will not save the data they input. and use it as an excuse to not use the web and continue use manual with excel. any sugestion?

Comment: Dont use focus because whenever user wants for some reason (copy paste for example) to go to different tab it won't let him. Well if they skip some fields let them know that nothing they inserted was saved at all.

Comment: I already make check all field when user try to save data. But still the user use it as an excuse. The user tell me that i should prevent user to by pass for filling the object, not just give a message after they save it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a standard javascript validation function, that does not depend on focus to force a user to fill all fields...

```
function validateForm() {
    var x=document.getElementById("ecode").value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
    {
        alert("Employee code must be filled out");
        return false;
    }

    x=document.getElementById("ename").value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
    {
        alert("Employee name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
    ...
    return true;
}

<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
    Employee code: <input type="text" id="ecode" name="ecode">
    Employee name: <input type="text" id="ename" name="ename">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the function used when form submit not prevent when the user filled an object. And it will increase the file size all form use the function.

Comment: This was just a basic example of how to validate form input... There's better library's out there [example](http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/) None on then rely on focus control though, because like I said it's a bad idea to do that...

Comment: That's true, but the user want this web can be used like they use a desktop program with visual basic like the previous applications. :-(